# Netlify: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve" for PDF

Tags: reactjs, netlify

My netlify project is failing to build because it can't locate a PDF saved within the project. This same project uses other files within this folder successfully, and the PDF works locally. I've checked the spelling and case-sensitivity and tried moving the PDF to other folders.

My goal is to link to the PDF in another tab/window, not to show it with my React App. This works locally.

[image: Netlify Error]
[image: PDF location]

Comment: What happens if you run `npm run build`/`yarn build`?

Comment: It compiles just fine when I run npm run build in VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

This may be one of the reason to your `module Not found`  error.
When you try to build on `Netlify` you should keep this in mind that it is `case sensitive` .
You are not alone. Often, case (as in: UPPERCASE or lowercase letters in filenames or paths) can cause problems.

This issue also happens regardless of where the case sensitivity occurs. To be really clear, during the build step:

`somefile.js != someFile.js != SomeFile.js != SOMEFILE.js != sOmEfIlE.js`

There is a discussion on this issue, [Here](https://answers.netlify.com/t/module-not-found-error-cant-resolve/17660/3)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did look into that and had no discrepancies there. My issue was the PDF not being uploaded to Github due to the GitIgnore file.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue. GitIgnore was preventing the PDF from being uploaded to my GitHub Repo. Removed the related GitIgnore code and problem is solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).